# How does a linear fractional function behave like a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

[image]

So I did the math for this and got

\begin{align*}
A &= a_1a_2 + b_1c_2\\
B &= a_1b_2 + b_1d_2\\
C &= c_1a_2 + d_1c_2\\
D &= c_1b_2 + d_1d_2.
\end{align*}

My book does not talk about how or where $A, B, C,$ and $D$ came from. It just talks about

$$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}.$$

How are these related and how are the values $A, B, C,$ and $D$ determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$f(x) = \frac{a_1x+b_1}{c_1x+d_1},\quad g(x) = \frac{a_2x + b_2}{c_2x+d_2},$$

then

$$(f\circ g)(x) = \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$$

where

$$\left[\begin{matrix} A & B\\ C & D\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} a_1 & b_1\\ c_1 & d_1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix} a_2 & b_2\\ c_2 & d_2\end{matrix}\right]$$

(you should verify this). Using the correspondence the other way (from $2\times 2$ matrices to fractional linear transformations), we have to make sure that at least one of the entries in the second row is non-zero - to ensure this condition is met, let's only consider invertible matrices from this point on (i.e. the general linear group). The association

$$\left[\begin{matrix}a &b\\ c& d\end{matrix}\right] \mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

is not injective because the matrices $A$ and $kA$ ($k\neq 0$) correspond to the same fractional linear transformation. To remove this ambiguity, we often consider matrices up to scale (the projectivised general linear group).

---

If you know some complex analysis, there is more to be said. In particular, the relationship between $\operatorname{PGL}(2, \mathbb{C})$, the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, and the fact that $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \cong \mathbb{CP}^1$.